# Colorize the Autocomplete list of the combobox

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using c# 4.0 on Windows Forms application,

I've a combobox with some items, i enabled the auto complete feature of it to SuggestAppend, with Auto complete source to ListItems (binded source)

now when user start typing, the auto complete list apears, I want to colorize those items in the autocomplete list depending on some condition,

I knew that there is a way to colorize the combobox items itself using DrawItem event handler, but i want to do this in the autocomplete list.

is this applicable ?? and how ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible.

The Windows feature that the .NET control is relying on:

[`SHAutComplete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759862%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

doesn't support this. So the .NET control that uses it cannot do it.